# How to reduce margins inside the equation environment?

Tags: equations, margins, fontsize

do you know a way to reduce margins inside the equation environment to be sure that a very long equation fits in a line (I have already reduced the fontsize of the equation)? Thanks

here my code:

```
\documentclass[11 pt,a4paper,oneside,openany, notitlepage]{article}
\input epsf
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\marginparwidth 0pt
\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin 0pt
\marginparsep 0pt
\linespread{1.5}
\topmargin 0pt
\textwidth 6.5in
\textheight 8.5 in

\begin{document}
{\tiny
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{l,t,R}^{(1)}(x_t,n;\theta)\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{x_t,n,T}-\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{1,x_t,n,T}\}-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,H_{l,t}^{(1)}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N_t=n)-\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(1)},X_t=x,N_t=n)\})\\
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{1,x_t,n,T}-\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{u,t,R}^{(1)}(x_t,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}_{x_t,n,T}\}-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(1)},X_t=x,N_t=n)-H_{u,t}^{(1)}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N=n)\})\\
\vdots\\
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{l,t,R}^{(2^{n-1})}(x_t,n;\theta)\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{x_t,n,T}-\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{2^{n-1},x_t,n,T}\}-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,H_{l,t}^{(2^{n-1})}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N_t=n)-\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(2^{n-1})},X_t=x,N_t=n)\})\\
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{2^{n-1},x_t,n,T}-\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{u,t,R}^{(2^{n-1})}(x_t,n;\theta)\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{x_t,n,T}\}-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(2^{n-1})},X_t=x,N_t=n)-H_{u,t}^{(2^{n-1})}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N_t=n)\})\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{equation}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Different equations might call for different remedies.  It would be helpful if you posted a minimum working example (MWE), starting with `\documentclass`, including your packages, and ending with `\end{document}`.  Think of the time it saves those trying to help you.

Comment: Well, you would to your reader a big favour by rewriting  this. No matter the margins, the equations are not particularly readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it as a `\parenVectorstack` in `\textstyle` math, if you wished.

```
\documentclass[11 pt,a4paper,oneside,openany, notitlepage]{article}
\input epsf
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\marginparwidth 0pt
\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin 0pt
\marginparsep 0pt
\linespread{1.5}
\topmargin 0pt
\textwidth 6.5in
\textheight 8.5 in
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\savestack{\rowA}{\Longstack[r]{%
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{l,t,R}^{(1)}(x_t,n;%
  \theta)\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{x_t,n,T}-\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{1,x_t,n,T}\}\\
-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,H_{l,t}^{(1)}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N_t=n)\\
-\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(1)},X_t=x,N_t=n)\})%
}}
\savestack{\rowB}{\Longstack[r]{%
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{1,x_t,n,T}-\frac{1}%
  {T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{u,t,R}^{(1)}(x_t,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}_{x_t,n,T}\}\\
-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(1)},X_t=x,N_t=n)\\
-H_{u,t}^{(1)}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N=n)\})
}}
\savestack{\rowC}{\Longstack[r]{%
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{l,t,R}^{(2^{n-1})}(x_t,n;%
  \theta)\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{x_t,n,T}-\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{2^{n-1},x_t,n,T}\}\\
-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,H_{l,t}^{(2^{n-1})}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N_t=n)\\
-\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(2^{n-1})},X_t=x,N_t=n)\})
}}
\savestack{\rowD}{\Longstack[r]{%
\max\{0,\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{2^{n-1},x_t,n,T}-\frac{1}%
  {T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\hat{H}_{u,t,R}^{(2^{n-1})}(x_t,n;\theta)\hat{\mathbb{P}}_{x_t,n,T}\}\\
-\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}^{}(\max\{0,\mathbb{P}(G_{\cdot j,t}=g_{\bullet}^{(2^{n-1})},X_t=x,N_t=n)\\
-H_{u,t}^{(2^{n-1})}(x,n;\theta)\mathbb{P}(X_t=x,N_t=n)\})
}}
\begin{equation}
  \setstackgap{L}{4\baselineskip}
  \parenVectorstack{\rowA \\ \rowB \\ \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\vdots} \\ \rowC \\ \rowD}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the line near the end to

```
\scalebox{.7}{$%
  \parenVectorstack{\rowA \\ \rowB \\ \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\vdots} \\ \rowC \\ \rowD}$}
```

would reduce the size of the object:

[image]